# Как передать в функцию call: types.CallbackQuery и message: types.Message?

Tags: python, aiogram

```
@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def send_random_value(message: types.Message, call: types.CallbackQuery):
    arr=["C:\парсинг\disss\Капча верефикация\captcha.png", "C:\парсинг\disss\Капча верефикация\captcha1.png", "C:\парсинг\disss\Капча верефикация\captcha2.png", "C:\парсинг\disss\Капча верефикация\captcha3.png", "C:\парсинг\disss\Капча верефикация\captcha4.png", "C:\парсинг\disss\Капча верефикация\captcha5.png", "C:\парсинг\disss\Капча верефикация\captcha6.png", "C:\парсинг\disss\Капча верефикация\captcha7.png", "C:\парсинг\disss\Капча верефикация\captcha8.png", "C:\парсинг\disss\Капча верефикация\captcha9.png", "C:\парсинг\disss\Капча верефикация\captcha10.png" ] # or imagefileid
    photo=open(random.choice(arr), "rb")
    await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo)
    if message.text  == 12:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Правильно, вот ваша ссылка: ')
    else:
        await bot.send_message(messsage.from_user.id, 'Неправильно, попробуйте снова')
```

Вот мой код, и он должен проверять кол-во символом в капче.
Я почти уверен, что у меня многое неправильно, но начало есть.
Проблема в том, что я не могу получить текст пользователя без message: types.Message, а без call нельзя получить message.text
Подскажите как решить проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш ответ на вопрос: никак.

1. Вы здесь используете обработчик коллбэков, и декоратор dp.callback_query_handler() используется именно для этого вопроса, то есть, допустим, обработка callback для какой-либо кнопки.
2. Советую Вам сначала принять текст от пользователи декоратором dp.message_handler() либо использовать состояния, если у нас четкие шаги.
3. После принятия сообщения обработать его.

Если Вы обрабатываете здесь кнопку, то вы даже не указали данные коллбэков.

Приведенный ниже код по сообщению "капча" от пользователя выполняет вашу задачу:

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text and message.text == "капча")
async def text_handler(message: types.Message):
    arr=["C:\парсинг\disss\Капча верефикация\captcha.png", ...] 
    photo=open(random.choice(arr), "rb")
    await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo)
    if message.text  == 12:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Правильно, вот ваша ссылка: ')
    else:
        await bot.send_message(messsage.from_user.id, 'Неправильно, попробуйте снова')
```

Comment: Это же не телебот, зачем вы делаете `@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text and message.text == "капча")` достаточно сделать `@dp.message_handler(text="капча")`

Comment: Посмотрел в документации, увидел `self.message_handlers.register(self._wrap_async_task(callback, run_task), filters_set)`
, где filters_set это наши фильтры, а все фильтры наши фильтры хранятся как HandlerObj в handler.py  - `record = Handler.HandlerObj(handler=handler, spec=spec, filters=filters)`.
Не знал, что так сработает, даже по документации не понял. Однако буду знать, спасибо.